# È corretto l'uso di "avvantaggiarsi" in questa frase?

Tags: word-usage

«Tra gli altri difetti, Chiara ha l'abitudine di avvantaggiarsi su di me parlando male di me e a sproposito.»

È corretto l'uso della parola "avvantaggiarsi" nella frase precedente?

La situazione è questa: io e Chiara siamo davanti ad un esaminatore. Lei parla male di me con l'obiettivo di influire sull'esaminatore e così ottenere un risultato migliore al test.

Comment: Dipende. Che intendi? Potresti parafrasare il senso che vuoi esprimere?

Comment: In un esame tra me e Chiara, lei prende vantaggio su di me parlando male. Grazie

Comment: Intendi “parlando male di te”? “Parlando male”, da solo, significa che non articola bene le parole, o che è sgrammaticata.

Comment: Intanto puoi chiarirti le idee [qui](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/avvantaggiare/), al punto 2.

Comment: Neanch'io capisco bene cosa vuoi dire.

Comment: Potresti dare un po' più di dettagli?

Comment: Scusate, cerco di esprimermi meglio: io e Chiara siamo davanti ad un esaminatore. Lei (Chiara) si approfitta di me (io ho usato avvantaggiarsi) parlando male per avere un risultato migliore al test.

Comment: Quindi, parla male di te?

Comment: E per il fatto di parlare male di te prende un voto migliore a questo esame?

Comment: Esatto, parla male di me

Comment: Quindi, il fatto di parlare male di te influisce sull'esaminatore?

Comment: Sì, per questo si avvantaggia

Comment: Penso che adesso si capisca cosa vuoi dire, ma forse si dovrebbe modificare il testo della domanda.

Comment: Cosa suggerisci?

Comment: Cerco di aiutarti a esprimere un po' meglio la tua domanda.

Comment: Credo tu possa dire "Tra gli altri difetti Chiara ha l'abitudine di provare a mettersi in migliore luce sparlando di me a sproposito." In questo caso inverti l'ordine  "luce migliore di me" --> "migliore luce" (in assoluto) e non ripeti "di me ... di me".

Comment: Quello che ho scritto è quello che volevi dire? Se vuoi anche tu puoi modificare la domanda. Soltanto devi fare clic su "edit".

Comment: si Chiaro, grazie,sei stato molto gentile :)

Comment: You should say "stata" and not "stato" because I'm a woman.

Answer (score 2):

Secondo quanto riporta il [dizionario](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/A/avvantaggiare.php) de *La Repubblica*, l'uso di *avvantaggiarsi* nel costrutto in esame non è scorretto, come si evince dall'accezione **B.2** della voce citata:

> Prendere vantaggio su un altro; superare; *avvantaggiarsi **sui** concorrenti*.

Facendo una ricerca su [Google Libri](https://www.google.it/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=avvantaggiarsi+su+qualcuno&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=_xxhWMDwB4_Y8gez36PABA#q=avvantaggiarsi+su+qualcuno&channel=fs&tbm=bks) se ne trovano svariati altri esempi.

---

Personalmente trovo ridondante l'uso dei *di me* in posizione ravvicinata nella frase in esame («di avvantaggiarsi su **di me** parlando male **di me**, *etc.*»). Si potrebbe ovviare utilizzando il verbo *[calunniare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/calunniare/)*, ad esempio in questo modo:

> Tra gli altri difetti, Chiara ha l'abitudine di avvantaggiarsi su di me calunniandomi e parlando a sproposito.

Comment: Ma “parlando a sproposito”, da solo, fa pensare che si metta a parlare di un argomento che non c'entra niente col resto.

Comment: Vero, ma mi pare che l'ambiguità sia presente anche nella frase originale. In ogni caso, cosa suggerisci, @DaG?

Comment: Boh, riformulerei in tutt'altro modo. Che ne so: “ha l'abitudine di farsi bella sparlando ingiustamente di me”.